# Can I convert a PNG's transparency into a selection?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a transparent PNG. Its transparency is defined by an alpha channel.

[image]

I am used to extracting this in PhotoPaint with a "Create selection from object" and this makes an exact match of the original transparency.

[image]

Is there a quick way to recover this transparency information into a selection or a channel in Photoshop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Photoshop hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd>(Mac <kbd>Command</kbd>) and click the image layer in the layers palette. That will load the alpha channel as a selection.

[image]

If you want to, after making the selection, you can also open the Channels palette and you click the "save selection as Channel" button.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. I guess now I will be Ctrl+Clicking, Alt+Clicking every corner I have not already clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply select with the magic wand the transparent area. This method takes only the full transparent area + what is needed for anti-aliasing if it's ON.

Comment: I tested this on a more complex transparency, but I do not think it works. Can you test it please? https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaAUo.png

Comment: @Rafael ok, it does not make feathered selection of partial transparency., I correct the answer.